# Django saving string without unicode characters

Tags: python, django

I want to save my string in CharField and then display it as a value of input.
But when I save it, I got value in unicode characters. ex.

```
When I type "a" and I save it I got "(u'a',)"
```

and I want to get only "a"

In my html code I have form:

```
 <form action="{% url 'edit'%}" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="text" name="name" value="{{data.name}}" placeholder="{% trans 'Name' %}" required><br>
 <button type="submit">{% trans 'Submit'%}</button>
 </form>
```

My views:

```
@login_required
def edit(request):
     user = MyUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
     if request.method == "POST":
        post = request.POST 
        editmodel = user.editmodel_set.all()[0]                 
        editmodel.name = post.get('name')
        shop.save()
```

And models:

```
class EditModel(model.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: I don't think your problem is connected to the string being unicode. Where exactly do you see this `(u'a',)`? Also, your view code looks incomplete.

Comment: It doesn't look good for user and if you save it one more time you get (u"(u'a',)",)

Answer (score 3):

That is not a good way of working with forms. Do not use data in `request.POST` directly to save in the database.

For more information refer [working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) in django documentation.

Either create a model form  or simple form, check posted data is valid and then save it in DB with appropriate data object.

---

If you still want to do that update your code as

```
editmodel.name = post.getlist('name')[0]
```